# Where do you put -Dvar=value arguments in Eclipse debug configurations?

Tags: java, eclipse, arguments

Title pretty much says it all. I'm moving to a new computer setup and I have to run an Eclipse configuration with a `-Dvar=value` argument. I forget where to put this in Eclipse. The debug configuration arguments tab doesn't seem to be the right place.

What are these parameters called and where do I enter them in a debug configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select from main menu Run/Debug Configurations, then choose your debug configuration or create new. Select tab "Arguments" and add your `-D...` to "VM arguments" text area.

Answer (score 4):

This is simple: just follow the "red color"

[image: Down arrow]

[image: Arguments]

Comment: I think you meant to highlight the "VM arguments" section instead of the "Program arugments"?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was too fast in 'print-screen'ing. I'm editing it now.

Answer (score 2):

Create a launch configuration, go to the Arguments tab and enter them in the "VM argument" field

Answer (score 1):

It is the right place. You have to put them inside the VM arguments text area.